# How can a line at the end of the code suddenly cause a bug in an earlier line?

Tags: python

Somehow I managed to create a program that gives an error in an earlier line by adding a line at the end.

The code below runs without any error.

However, if I uncomment the last line an error occurs in the line before that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/code.py", line 233, in <module>
    print(current_step.right.down)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'down
```

This bug is caused because the program tries to jump to a node that is outside of the grid, but I don't understand why that bug doesn't show up if comment out the last line.

```
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, year, day):
        self.year = year
        self.day = day

grid = '''7.77F7F|-F.J-J7-LF|-7.FFL7F-L-7--7-JF-7F.LL.7-|FFF7..F-7-J777FF.77.L-FL-7-FF77-L7-F-F--FJFF|-F77F-7F7-.L-FFL-|-7-LJ77F7-F-FJ77.77J.J77F-L77.
F-F-J|FL-J7-L|.L|FJ|LF-7JL|J.|J.||LLJJLJ-.L7F7|L7|L7-L7J.|LJ-JJ-JJ-|F77.|.LLFJLLJ-JFJJF|-F-J7.LL7.J7J-7.7-|.LJFF.|-J7L--|..|-F--J||LF-|7.|-.
FF-JF77.L7--7F--JLF|LL-L-.7-|J-L7|7F|.J.L7.|.-7L-77J.L|.L--7-|..FL7LFJLF|7JLL|||J..|7|7.|L|F|7JFL-JF7-F-|.J-7F7..FJ|||L7F77.FL-|77JL|-FF-||7
|.||L7JFLF7L7.|J|LLJ7JF-JL-7|7-FL7L|J7JF--.|7||-FFJL|F|F|77F-|-|7L--|FLJ|L7.L|-J--.J-|-F|.LJ.-7LLJ7L7F|-F-|7LJ.FF|F||F|.||LF-L-|JL7FL.LLF-77
7F|-|L7JF|7JL.F-7.F-J-FJLJFLJ7J||L-|L--J|J--J|J|F77LF---7-F7F7FF7F|FJ7JLJ.J7F7LF|L7LF.|.LF-77|F-J|JLF7F777F-|J7FFL7|F7LJ777.-7F|.FJJ|7FL||||
L-JJJLJ-FJ-7FJ7FJ-F-7.L7F|F|7F7LJ7FL7|--|F7J.777||F7L-7FJFJ|||F7JF-J|77|L|JFLJ.FJF|7LJ-.F-JFF-J..|77|LJL77J.|LJ7.L--.L7--F-J||J-|L|JF-77LL7J
LL7F--7FJ.F--L77.|FF|-LJJF7-JFJLF77F7J|7FF7F7F7FJ||L7FJ|FJFJ|LJL77-LLJL7.|-FJ.|.FL|LFJLFL7F|..FFF7J7L-7FJL|-L7LF7FLJ7FF-.JJ7FJ7JF-J-J7LJFF|J
F.F|FJ--7.F--7|F--||..FJJ7JJLL7FFL77.|L|JF7|||||FJ|FJL7|L7L7|F--J|||LFJ77F-|FL7FLJL|J7.|-|J..|7FJ|.|LFJ|.L||-7FJ|L7L-|.|..|LF7FFJ7JFF-J7-J.J
--LJ|||.L-F-LFLJLLJ--7--LJ-.LFLFJLJ7FF.FFJ||LJLJ|FJL--JL7L7|||F7-LFJ-JF|JJFF7JL--F|F7.-J|.|L-F7L7L-7FL7L77L--LL|JL7L7.777.|JL|JJ.|F-J.L7-LL.
L7.L|-7-L-77-JFL.|JF-J|J|LFFF-J|L-JFF--7L7|L-7F-JL----7FJFJLJLJL7JJLF-JJFLFJ|-|7FF-JL7FF7-F-L||7L-7|F7|FJF77F7|L|-J7L--77LF...FLLL77|F7||J.J
FJJ.|FJ|JFL77-LLF7FJ-F-.7F7--|FJJ-FFJF7L-JL7L||F-7F7F-J|FJF-----J7.7L7F-7-L7L7F-7|F7FJ7FF7F7|||JFFJ||LJL7||F7F-7|.F---FF|JF-J77F|.JFJ--L--J|
|-|L7-7J77JLJF|.L.FL7.FJ7F7J7FF7.FFL-JL7F-7L7|||FJ||L-7|L7L-7F7F7--|7L--FF-L7|L7|||||.FFJ|||FJ|JFJFJL--7|||||7|LF7-JFFF7JFJJ.7-J|-|FL77||-7F
F---|LJLF-7-JJ-JJ|LF7FL7|F7-|L|L7F7F7|LLJLL7||||L7||F7||L|F-J|||||F|-7-F--7F||FJ|||LJF-JFJ||L7L7L7L7F7FJ||||L7F7||FLFF|L7JJ|7L|.--FJ--J--.7-
LJJ.L7|7LFJ|FLJ7L|-JJ7-FL7LF--JFJ|||L7.FF7-|||||FJ|||LJL7|L--JLJL-7JL|J|F7L-J|L7LJL7JL7FJFJ|FJFJFJFJ|||FJ|||FJ|LJL77JF|FJ|F|.7|7--J7FL7.LFJ|
-JF7.L--|L-J7F-J|L7J|FF7L7.L--7|FJ||FJF7||FJLJ|||7||L--7LJF7F-7F--JJFF7LJL--7|FJF--J|FJL7L7|L7|FL7L7|LJL-JLJL7L--7L7-F||7||LJL||FJJ|-|FF.--J
|-||7-|7|7.L|JF7|J|L7L-F-F--7FJ||FJ||7||||L7F7LJL7|L---JF-JLJ-LJ|F--7|L7FF7FJLJFJF-7-L-7|FJL-JL7FJFJL--7F----JF--JFJF-JL--7F|-JJJJFJ.F7JFLJ.
F7.F--F-LL77.7L-J.FF77-7FL-7|L7|||-||FJ|||JLJL7F-JL----7L--7F7F--JF-JL7L7|||F--JFJFJFF7||L---7FJL7||LF-JL--7F7L--7|-L7F---J---L77F|FFJ.|L|-7
LJ-|7-7.FJL7..777.FJ.77|F--JL-JLJ|FJ|L7LJL7-F7|L-7LF7F7L7F-J|LJF--JJF7L7||||L-7FJFJ.FJ||L-7F7||F7|L7FJF----J|L-7FJ|F7||F-7.|F|L|-|77.JF--L-7
LF-LFFJ-7-LLF77JLFFJ7JLL|F----7F-JL7|FL--7L7|||F-JFJLJL-JL7J|F-JF-7FJ|FJ||||F-JL7L-7L7|L-7||LJ||||FJL7L-7F--JF-JL7LJLJLJFJ-7F|7J.L7JFJ-|7FJ|
-J.|||F-77J||FJL7LF7J.|LLJF7F-J|F-7|L7F7FJFJ||||F7L-----7FJFJL-7L7||FJ|FJ||||F7FJF-JFJL7.||L-7||||L7L|F-J|F--JF-7L7F-7F-J|J||L7L|F-.J-FJFJ.7
L|-L|JF77..LLL--F-J|L-F7F7||L-7LJFJ|FJ||L7L7||||||F7|F7.||FJF7FJFJ|||FJ|FJ|||||L7L-7L7FJFJL--JLJ||FJFJL-7||.F7|FJFJL7|L-7JJLJ-|7||L7|FJJ-L-L
F77.7FJJJF7.L|J.|F7L7L|||LJ|F7L-7|FJ|FJL7|FJ|||LJ||L7||FJ||FJLJFJFJ||L7|L7LJ|||FJF-JFJL7|F---7F7LJL7|F7FJ|L7|LJL-JF-JL7FJ|FFJFL|JLF|F|LJ|L||
LJL-J-J..F7FF-.FLJ|FJ.||L-7LJL--JLJFJL7FJ||FJ|L-7LJFJ|||FJ|L7F7|FJFJ|FJL7L-7||LJFJF7L7FJLJF-7LJL--7|||LJ.L7LJF----JF-7LJLFJ.LF-|JJL.-LJ.FJL7
F||LJ.7FJ-|7|JF7LFJL7FJ|F7L--7F-7F7L--JL-JLJFJF7|F-JJ|||L7|FJ|||L7L7||F-JF-JLJF7|L||FJL-7FJFJF7F--JLJL7F7LL7FJF7F7FJFJF-77-||.F|7-.FLF-|L-77
J----7.--77FF-JL-JF-JL7LJ|7F7LJFJ|L---7F----JFJ||L-7FJ||FJ|L7||L7|FJ|||F7L--7FJLJFJ||F--JL7L7||L--7F-7LJ|F-J|FJLJLJFJJL7L--7-FJL|-LF-JFJFFJ|
L-|-L7.JJF-7L----7|F77L-7L7||F7L-JF---JL7-F-7L7LJF7|L7||L-JFJ||FJ|L7LJLJL7F-J|F7|L7|||F7-FJFJ||F-7|L7L--JL-7|L7F--7L-7FJF--J-F7.|FJ.|F7.F|-7
|F-JL77FFL7|F7F-7|||L7F7L7|||||F7.L----7L7L7L7|F7|LJFJ||F--JFJ|L7L-JF7F7FJL-7|||F7|||||L7L7||||L7LJFJF-7F7FJL-JL-7L--J|FJF7.FJL-7|.J-JJFLL-J
F-JFFJFFF7|||LJFJ||L7|||F|LJ||LJL7JF7F7|FJFJFJLJ||F7L7LJ|F7.L7L7L7F-JLJLJF-7|||LJLJLJ|L7|FJL7|L7L-7L-JFJ||L7F----JF-7F|L-JL7L7F-J-JJJ7F7.L-J
|J.||-F-JLJ|L-7L-JL-JLJL7L7FJL7F7L-J||||L7|FJF--J||L7L-7||L7FJFJFJ|F7F7F7L7LJ|L-7F--7L7|LJF-JL7|F7|F--JFJL-JL--7F7|FJFJF---JFJL7JJ.JFFJ-7J7F
F..|J-L---7|F7L--7F-7F-7L7|L-7LJL--7LJ||FJ|L7L--7||FJF-J|L7||FJJL7LJLJ||L7L-7|FFJL-7L-JL-7|F7.|LJ||||F7L--7F--7LJLJL-JFJF--7L7FJJF|.FJ|J|7F|
FF7.|FJ7F7|||L---JL7LJ7|FJL-7L7|F-7L7FJ||FJFJ7F-JLJ|LL7FJFJLJL7F-JF---JL7L7FJL7|F7FJ|F-7FJLJL7L-7||L7|L7F7||F7L----7F-JJ|F-JFJL-7F77|LJ-J-J7
|L--|7|L|LJLJF7F7F7|F--J|7F7L7L7|FJFJL7||L7L-7L-7F-JF-JL7L7F--JL-7L--7F7L7LJF-J||LJF7L7|L-7F-JLFJLJFJ|FJ|LJLJL7-F77LJJF-JL7FJF--J|L7J|L-J.J.
|LL7|JL-L7F7FJ||||||L7F7L-JL7L7|||FJF-J||JL7FJ-FJ|F7L--7|FJL7F7F7|F--J||7L-7L7FJL-7||FJL7-|L7F7L7F7|.||-L-7F--JFJL-7-FJF-7||FJF7J|FJ|F7|F7-|
||F-JFJF7|||L7||||LJ7||L---7L-JLJ|L7|F7|L7FJ|F7|FJ||F7FJ||F-J|LJ|||F7FJ|F7|L7||F--J|LJF-JFJFJ||FJ|LJFJL77FJL---JF--JFJFJFLJ||-|L7||F--77||F|
F|7JFLFJLJ|L7|LJLJ-F7LJF7F7L-7F-7L7|||||FJ|FJ||||-|||||FJ||F7|F-J||||L7|||F7||||F7-L7FJF7L7|J|||FJF7L7FJFJF----7L--7|FJF77FJL7L7||||F-J7-FF7
L7J-7-L-7FJJLJF7LF-JL7FJLJL7FJ|FL7||LJLJ|FJL7||||FJLJ||L7|LJ||L7FJ|||FJ||||||||LJL7FJ|FJ|FJ|FJLJL7||FJ|FJFJLF7LL---J|L7||FJF-JFJLJLJL7JJ|JL|
7LLJ|7.FJL-7|F|L-JF-7|L---7|L7|F-JLJF-7FJ|F-J|LJ|||F7||FLJF-JL7||FJ||L7||||||LJFF-JL7LJFLJFJL7LF-J|LJ|LJ7L--JL------JFJ||L7L--JF--7F-J.FL7F|
|7L-77-L7F-JF7L---JFJL----JL7LJL----JFJL7||F7L-7||FJLJ|F77L-7FJLJ|FJ|FJLJLJ|L--7L-7FJLF---JF-JFJF7|F--------------7F7L-JL-JF-7FJF7|L7J.|JFL7
LL7.L-7FLJF-JL---7FJF-7F---7L-7F--7F-JF7|||||F7|LJL7F7LJL7F-J|F7F|L7||-F---JF--J7FJL-7|F-7FJF-JFJ||L7F7F------7F-7|||F7F7F7|.|L-J||FJJ.-7|--
..-7LL|7|LL-----7LJFJLLJF-7L-7|L-7|L-7||LJLJ|||L-7FJ||F-7|L-7LJL7L-JLJFJF7F7L--7FJF7FJ||FJ|-L-7|7LJFJ|LJF-----J|FJ|||||||||L7|F--J|||F-JLL-7
-F7F..|J7.LF-7F7L--J-FF7L7|F-J|F-JL--J|L7F--J||F7|L7||L7|L7FJF--JF7F-7L7|LJL7F7|L7|||FJ|L7L-7FJ|F7JL-JF7L-7F7F7|L7LJLJLJ|||FJ|L--7LJ-L7FJJ77
F-7|L7|.F-F|FJ|L----7FJL-J|L-7|L------JFJL7F7|||LJFJ|L7||FJL7L---J||FJJLJF--J|LJFJ|LJ|FJFJF-J|FJ|L----JL--J|||LJFJLF7F-7|||L7L7F-JF7JJLJ7.-7
7LLJ7LJFF--J|FJF---7|L---7|F7||F7F-----JF7LJLJ|L7FL7L7|||L7J|F7F-7LJL---7|F-7L7|L7L-7||LL7L-7||7|F-7F-7F-7F|||F-JF7|||FJLJL-J||L7|||L7J.L-||
L7L|LJ-FL--7|L-JF7J|L----JLJLJLJ|L------JL---7L7|F-JFJ|||FJFJ||L7L7F-7F7|LJ|L7L-7|F-J||F7L7FJ||FJL7LJ-|L7L-JLJL--JLJLJL---7JF7L-JFJL7J-F.-L-
|LFF.|.F---JL7F-JL-JF----------7|F7F-7F------JF||L7FJFJ|LJFJFJ|FJFJL7|||L--7FJF7|||F7LJ|L-JL7|||F-JJF7L-JF-7F-7F7F7F7F7F7FJFJL---JF-JJ.F7.|J
F--F77FL----7|L-----JF---------JLJLJL|L-------7||FJL7L7L7FJFJ-LJJ|F7|LJ|F-7|L7||||LJL-7L7F7FJ|||L7F-JL---J|LJLLJ||LJ||LJLJ7L7F---7L7JF-J|-77
|J-FF-7J.F--JL--7F7F7L7F7F7F7F7F----7|F7F7F--7|LJ|F7L7L7|L7L--7F7LJ|L-7||FJ|-|||||F7F-JL||||FJ|L7|L--7F7F-7F---7LJF7LJJF7F7FJ|F-7L-JFJF-J--J
L|LLL7|FFL-----7|||||FLJLJLJ||||F---J||LJ|L-7|L-7|||FJ7|L7|F7FJ|L7FJF7||||FJFJ|LJ||||F--J|LJL-JLLJF--J|LJFJ|F7FJF-JL--7|LJLJFJ|FJ|JL|FJ7.L|J
LL7-L||F7F7F-7FJLJLJL-7F7F7FJ|LJL7F7|LJF7L--JL--JLJ||F-JFJ|||L-JFJL7|LJLJLJFJFJF-J|||L--7|7F7.F--7L---JF7L-J||L7L7F---J|F---J|||F777||F7F7|J
.LFJL|LJLJ|L7LJF7F---7||||LJFJF7LLJL7F-JL---7FF7F-7LJL7FJFJ||F-7L7FJL---7F7L7L7|F7|||F--JL7|L7L-7||F77FJL---JL-JFJL7F7FJ|F7|F7|||L7FJLJLJL-7
--L7.L7F-7L-JF7|||F77||||L--J|||F7F-JL7F---7L-JLJFJFF-J|FJFJ||-L-JL-7F--J|||L7|LJ||LJL7F7FJL7|-FJL-JL7L----7-F-7|F-J||L7||L-J||||FJ|F---7F7|
|FLJL7LJFL---J||||||FJLJ|F----JLJ|L---JL--7L7F7F7L7FJF7|L7|FJL--7JF7|L---JL7FJL7FJ|F-7||||F7|L7|F-7F7L----7L7L7|||.FJL7|||F--J|||L-JL--7||LJ
FF.FFLFF-----7LJLJ|LJF-7|L----7F7L-------7L7||LJL7|L-JLJ7||L7F-7|FJ||F7F7F7|L7FJL-JL7|||LJ||L7LJL7LJL--7F7L7L7|||L-JF7LJLJ|F--JLJF7F7F7|||J7
L7.-|-FJF---7L----JF7|FJ|F7F--J|L-------7L-JLJF7FLJF-----J|FJ|J|LJFJ||||||LJFJL--7F-JLJ|F-JL-JF-7L7FF--J|L7L7LJLJF-7|L----J|F-7F-JLJ||LJLJ-7
FJJ.F.|FJF--JF-7F--JLJL7LJLJF7FJJF------JF--7FJL7F7L--7F7FJL7L7L7FJJLJ|||L7.L7F7FJ|F---JL----7|7L7|FJF--JFJ.L7F--J7|L------JL7|L---7LJJLL|-|
L7LF|-LJ|L-7FJ-LJLF----JF-7FJ||F7L----7F7L-7LJF7LJL--7|||L7L|FJFJL---7LJL7|F-J|||FLJF-7F-----JL-7||L7L7F-JF--J|F7F7L7F-7F7F-7||F7F-J.F7.JJLJ
LJ-J|LL-F--JL7F--7L----7|J|L7LJ|L----7LJL--JF-JL-----JLJL7|FJL7L7F7F7L7-FJ|L7FJ|L--7L7LJF--7F7F7||||L-JL-7L-7FJ|||L7|L7||||L||LJ|L7JF|L77.|7
.|..LFJ.L---7|L-7L-----J|FJFJF7|F---7L-----7|FF-----7F7F7LJL--JFJ||||FJLL7L7LJFJF--JFL-7|F-J|||||||F-----JF7|L-JLJFJ|FJ||||FJL-7L-JF-JFJJJ-L
-LJFLLF--LF-J|F-JF7F7F7FJL7|FJ|||F--JF7F--7LJFJF----J|||L7F--7FJFJ||LJ||LL-J|LL-JF7-F--J||F-J||LJLJL------J||F7F7FJ.LJ|||||L7F7L-7L|F-JJ|LFJ
L|-F77||..L--JL--JLJLJLJ.LLJL7LJ|L---JLJF-JF-JFJFF7F7||L7||F-J|FJ7||JJ|7-LJL|J7F-JL-JF7FJLJF7LJLF7F7F------JLJ|||L----7||||FJ||F7L-JL-7|L77J
F|-JLLJ-7.F7F7F-------7F7F--7L7FJF------JF-JF-JF7||||||FJLJL-7LJF7||7F|-7JJ.|.FJF-7F7|LJ|F-J|F--J||||F------7FLJL----7|LJLJL-JLJL7F-7FJ77|L-
LFJ-7J|.LFJ|||L------7LJ|L-7|.LJ|L-----7FJF7L--J||||||LJF-7F-JF-J|LJ7|||.|LFFFJFJJLJLJF-7L-7|L7F7|||LJF77F--JF77F7F7.||FF-------7|L7||||L77|
J.L.7-|7.L7LJL7F7F7F7|F-JF7||F--------7LJFJL7F7FJ|||||F7L7|L--JF7L-7JLJ7.J.FJ|FJFFF7F7|FJF7||JLJ|||L7FJ|FJF--JL-JLJL7LJFJF-7F-7FJL7||L77L7J7
.|.F||LF7LL--7LJLJLJLJL--J|||L-------7|F7L-7LJLJ-|LJLJ||FJL--7FJL7FJJ.|77.F--||--FJLJLJL-JLJL7F7||L7|L7|L7L7F---7F--JF7|FJLLJ|||JJLJL-JJL|.L
F|.F7|J|FL|F7L---7F7F---7FJ||F7F7F---JLJ|F-JF7F--JF7F-J|L---7|L-7||7.-JF---JLLJ7LL-7F-7F7F--7LJLJL-JL-JL-J-|L--7|L---J||L----7LJL7.FLJ|-L77|
||-LJ-7|LJFJL----J|||F--JL-JLJLJ|L---7F7|L--JLJF-7||L7FL---7|L--JLJ-|FJ||FLJ.J.77FFJ|FLJLJF7L-7F7F7F7F-7F--JF7FJL7F7F-J|F----JF|FF77JL7.LJ77
LJ.LL7JJ77L7F----7|||L7F-7F7F-7FJF7F7LJ|L7F-7F7L7LJL-JF7F7|LJ|F7F77.L|L|77.|FF-F--JFJF7F--JL--J|LJ|||||LJF-7|LJF7LJLJFFJL---7F7F7|L-7-777JL7
FJ-JJLJ.77FJ|F---J|||.|L7||||FJL-J|||F-JF|||||L7L-----JLJL-7F-JLJL--7J|LJLF|-|||F7FJFJLJF7F7F7FJF-J|||F--JFJL--JL7F7F7|F----J|LJ||F-J-LL|.7J
F7LFF7|F--JFJ|F7F7|||FJFJLJLJL-7F7LJ|L--7||FJL7|F---7F--7F7LJF-7F7F-J.7.L-7J7|-LJLJ|L--7|LJLJLJ.L--J||L--7L-----7LJLJ||L7LF-7|F-J|L-7FFJJFFJ
|7.FL|7L7F-JFJ|LJ||||L7|F------J||F7L---J|||F7||L--7|L-7|||F-J.||LJ|LJ-L--FJFJ7.||LFFF-JL-77F--7FF-7||7F7L-7F--7L-7F-JL7L-JFJ||F7|F-J7||J|J7
J--7|LJ|LJ|LL7|LFJ|||FJ|L7F7F--7|LJL----7LJLJ|||F--J|F7||||L--7LJ-|7|-|7FL|||L-L77-FFJF---JFJF7L-JFJLJFJL--J|F-JF7LJ7F7|F--JFJLJLJL7LF777L-J
|J|.F-F-|7F.LLJFJFJLJL-JFLJLJJFJ|F--7F7FJ7F-7|||L--7||||||L7F-JF-7.7J-F|...J77LFLFF7L7|F--7L7|L--7|F7FJF---7||LFJ|F7FJLJ|F7-|F7F-7FJ-F77-|LL
LFFF7LF-FJ7.FLFL-JF-7F-7F7F7F7L-JL-7LJ|L--JFJ||L7F7|||||LJFJL--JFJ7|..FJ.|-|JJLF-FJL-J||F-J7LJJF-JLJLJFJF--J|L7|FJ|||F-7LJL-J|LJJLJF-J|7|L.J
FFJ||--7|F7-|.FF-7L7|L7LJ|||||F7F--JF7L----JL||LLJLJLJ||F7L7F7F7|J7JL-||F7|J|7F|.L7F7FJ||F7F7F7L7F--7FJLL--7|FJ|L-JLJL7|F7F-7L---7FJF7L77FJ.
J7-JJ-LFJJJ.LF7L7L7|L7L-7LJLJLJ|L---JL------7LJF7F7F7LLJ|L7LJ||LJ||.|.L|J|7-JF-LL7||||FJLJ||||L-J|F-J|F----J||FJF-7F--JLJ|L7|F--7LJFJ|FJLJJ7
L||L.F.|7J-F.||7L7||FJF7L-----7|F7F-7F------JF-JLJ||L7F7|FJF7LJF7F7-F-FJL|-7J|J.LFLJLJL7F7LJ|L7F7|L7FJL7F---JLJFJJ|L----7L-J|L-7L7FJFLJJ-|.F
LF-7FF-J7-FJF|L--JLJL7|L-77F7FJLJ|L7LJF7F-7F7|F7F-J|FJ||||FJL--JLJL7J..F7J|-.L77L|J|F7.LJL-7||LJLJJLJF7LJF-7F7FJF7L7F7F7L--7|F7|JLJJLJ|...FF
|L-J-7..--F7FJF--7F-7|L-7L-JLJF-7L7L--JLJFJ||LJ|L--JL-JLJLJF-7F7F--J||-.F7J.7-J|.LJF||F-7F7||F------7||F-JFJ||L-JL7LJ||L---JLJ||.||.|JJL.--.
F-F|-|F7.F|LJFJF7LJFJL--JF7F-7|JL7L-----7|FJL7FJF--7F-7F7F7|FJ|LJ-|7LJL.LJ.FLLFF7JFFJ|L7|||||L-----7|||L-7L7||F7F7L-7|L--7F7F7||F777..LLFJ|7
JFF--|F--L|F7|FJL--JF7F--JLJ|LJF7L-----7LJL-7|L7|F7LJ-LJLJLJL7|7JFJLF7JFLL-F7FF||F7L7|FJLJLJ|F-----JLJL-7L7LJ||LJL--JL--7LJLJ|LJ|L-7--F7J7L|
|7J|.L-7F7LJLJL----7|||F-------JL-----7L7F7FJL-JLJ|F7FF----7LLJ7LJJL-J77.FFF7-FJLJL7|LJF---7|L7F--7F7F-7L-JF7|L----7F7F7|F7F-JF-JF-J7J|F.JFJ
J|FL7|.7JF7||F-7F7L||||L--------7F---7L-J|LJF7F7F7LJL7L7F--J77|7-|JLF7-F-7F||FL--7FJL--JF--JL7LJF7LJLJFJF7-|||F-7F-J||||LJ|L--JF-J7L77LJFL|.
|L7FF--J-J7|FL7LJ|FJ|LJF--------J|F--JF7F|F7|||LJ|F7FJFJL7LF7F7.F-7.FLJL7|7||F77FJL--7JFJF--7L--JL7F7FJFJL7||LJ-LJLFJLJL7LL----JF777LFJL-JF.
F-J-J|J.|-F7F7L-7||FJ.FJF7F7F--7FJL---JL-J|LJ|L7FJ||L-JF7L-JLJL-7|F7JF77|L-JLJL7|F7F7L-JFJF-JF---7LJLJFJF-J|L------JF--7L----7FFJL7--..|.FL|
L7J-|77FLFJLJL-7||LJF7L-JLJ||F7LJ..F7F----JF7L-JL-J|F7FJ|F7F----JF-7-FLFL-----7|LJLJL7F-JFJF7|F--JF7F-J.L--JF-------JF7|F----JFJF-J||77F|--J
|||F.F-JJ|F---7LJL--JL----7LJ|L--7FJ|L---7FJL-----7LJ||LLJ|L-7LF-JFJF--F---7F-JL7F7F7LJF7L7|LJL---JLJF77F---J|F7LF-7F||LJ7F---JFJ7FLF7F7.7.7
F77JL.|FF||F-7L-----7F--7FJF7L--7|L7|F7F7LJF-----7L-7|L7F7|F-J.L-7|F7-LL--7|L-7FJ|LJL-7|L7LJF7F7F7J.FJL7L-----JL7L7L-JL--7|F-7FJLFJ|FJFL-JFJ
||L--7-JLLJL7L-----7LJLFJL-J|F7FJL-JLJ|||F7L----7L--JL-J|LJ|F77F7||||F---7|L7FJL7L---7||FJF-JLJLJL7FJF7L--------JFJF7F7F7LJL7||F7J||J.||7JFJ
|-7LL|JF--F-JF----7L-7FJF--7LJLJF7F--7LJ||L-7F-7L-7F7F77|F-J|L7|LJ|||L--7||FJL7FJF--7|LJL7L-7F-7F7LJFJL-----7F7F-JFJLJLJL---J|LJL7F7LFFF-F-7
|7|L||F|L||F7|F---JF7LJFJF-JF7F-JLJF7L-7|L-7|L7|F7||LJL7LJF7|FJ|F7||L7JFJ|||JFJL7L-7|L-7FJF7LJ7LJ|F7L7F-----J|||F-JJ7F7F----7L7F-JF7.|LFJ|||
--LFFJ7J7FLJ|||F7F7||F7|FJF-JLJF---JL7FJL--JL7|||LJ|F-7L7FJ||L7LJ||L7L-JFJ|L7|F7L7FJ|F7||-||F----J||FJL7F7F7FJLJL--7FJ||F---J-LJF7||-7FLFJJ.
LF7||L-7-FJFJ|LJ||||||LJL-JFF--JF--7.LJF----7LJ||F-J|7L-J|FJL7L7FJ|J|F--JFJFJLJ|FJL7||||L7|LJF--7FJ||F7LJLJLJF----7LJFJ|L-----7FJ|||77LF77L.
||LJJ7.J.L-L-JF7LJLJLJF-----JF--J|FJF--JF7F7|F7LJL-7L7F7||L-7|FJ|FJFJ|F7-L7|LF-JL--JLJ||FJL--JF7LJ|LJ||F7F7F7L---7|F-JFJF-7F--JL7LJL-77||7JF
L7LJ7-|-FF|JF-JL---7F7L--7F--JF7F7L-JF--JLJ|LJL7LF7|FJ|L7L7FJ||FJL7L7LJL-7|L7L--7F-7F-J|L7F7F7|L7F---JLJLJLJL-7F7|||F7L7|F|L---7L7F7FJJFJ|-7
|--L-F---7JLL----7FJ||7F-J|F--JLJL---JF7F7||F7FJFJ||L7|FJFJ|7||L-7L7|F---JL7L--7LJFJL-7|FJ|||||FJLS---------7|||||LJ|L-JL7|F---JFJ||L77L7-.|
|LF..L|LFL7.LF---JL-JL7L7FJL---------7|LJL7LJLJ7|FJ|FJ|L7L7|FJ|JFJFJ|L7FF7FJF--J-FJF--J||FJLJLJ|F7F77F7F---7L7||LJFFJF7F-J||F7-FJFJL-J7..LF7
|.|.FJ|L|L|7FL7F-----7L7LJF------7|F7LJF-7L7F--7|L7|L7L7|FJ|L7L7L7L7|FJFJ|L7|F77FJFJF-7|||F---7|||||FJLJF-7L-JLJF7FJFJ||F7LJ|L7L7L7F7F--7-F7
|7FFJ-L-J|F-JLLJF7FF7|FJF7L---7F7L-JL--JJL-JL7FJ|FJ|FJFJ|L7L7L7|.|FJ||JL7|FJ|||FJFJFJFJ||LJF7|||||||L---JFJ-F--7|LJFJ|LJ||F7|FJFJFJ|LJF7L7J|
.FJ|LF|-|7.||7-FJL-JLJL7||F--7LJL--7F-----7F7||FJL7||7L7|-L7L7||FJL-JL7FJLJFJ|||FJ7L7L7|L7FJL7|||LJL7F7F-JF7|F-JL7FJF7F7|||||L-JFJFJF7|L-JL-
-L-7-LL-L--7LF-JF7F7F-7|||L-7L-----J|F----J|LJ|L-7|||F-JL7J|FJ||L7F---JL--7|FJ||L-7.L7||FJL-7||||F--J|LJF-JLJ|F7FJL-JLJLJLJLJF-7L-JFJLJJ.|7.
|-FJ|.J7FL-|-L-7|||LJ||||L7FL-------JL-7.F7L-7L7-||||L-7FJFJL7||FJL7F7F-7J|||FJ|F-JF-J|||F7FJ||LJL7F7L--JF--7LJLJF7F--7F7F--7|-L7F7L-7JLFL|7
|-J-J-77FLF.F|-LJLJJF-J|L7|F7F------7F7L7|L7.L7|FJLJL7L||FJF-J||L7FJ||L7|FJ||L7||F7L-7|||||L7|L-7FJ||F---JF7L7F--J|L-7LJLJF7|L-7LJ|F7|-F-7LJ
-J.F|F-LJLF--7F7F---JF7L7||||L7F-7F7LJL-JL7L77||L-7F-JFJ|L7|F7||FJL7||FJ||FJ|FJ|LJ|F7|||||L7|L7FJL7||L----JL7LJF-7|F7L7F7F||L--JF7LJLJ|L-JLL
LF7|F-JL7|L7FJ||L----JL7LJLJL-J|L||L7F7F-7L7|FJL7FJL7FL7L7||||||L-7LJ||FJ|L7||FJF-J|||LJ||FJL7LJF-J||F-7F--7L--JFJLJL-J|L-JL---7|L7-||JFLJL|
L|JF7-7---FJ|FJ|F7F7|F7L7F7F-7FJFJ|FJ|||FJ7||L7FJ|F-JF7|FJ||||||F7L-7|||7L7|||L7|F7||L7FJ||F7|F-JF7||L7|L-7L---7|F--7F7|F------J|FJF7--J7-F|
7-FJL7LF--L7|L7LJLJL-JL-J|||FJ|JL-JL7|||L7FJL7||FJ|F7|||L7||||||||F7|||L7FJ||L7||||||FJ|FJ|||||F7|||L7||F7L---7|LJF-J|LJL-----7FJL-J|.-J|.F7
L-7---FJLFFJ|FL---7F-7F7FJLJL-JF----J|LJFJL7LLJ|L7LJ||||FJ|||LJLJ|||||L7LJL|L7||||LJ|L7|L7|||||||||L7|||||F7F-J|F7|F7|F-7F----J|F---J7J7F7F7
FF--JF-7.LL7L-----J|FJ|LJF--7F-JF--7FJF-JF-JF--JFJF-J|LJL7||L--7FJ|||L-JF--JFJ|||L7FJFJL7|||||LJ||L-JLJ|||||L7JLJ|LJLJ|-||-F---JL---7JFL7FJJ
L7JL-JJ|7|F|F7F7F7FJL7|F7|F7LJF7|F-J|FJF7L7.L7F7|FL7FJF--J|L7F7|L7|LJF--JF7FJFLJL7||FJF-J|LJ|L-7|L---7FJ|||L7L--7L7F-7L7LJFJF7F7F---JFJL|-|J
FF7L7|.LLF-J||||||L7FJ||LJ|L7FJ||L7FJL7|L-JF-J||L-7|L7L--7|FJ||L7LJF-JF--J|L-7JF-J|LJLL-7L-7|F-J|F---JL7||L7|F--J||L7L7L--JFJLJ|L--77J.LFJ|7
J.FL7F7J|L-7|LJLJL-J|FJL-7|||L7LJJLJF7|L-7FJF7|L7FJL-J7F-J|L7|L7||FJF7L--7|F7L7|F7L7-F--JF7|||F-JL7F7LFLJL7||L--7FJFJ|L7F7FJF7FJF--J-7F7|-JJ
FLJFLJL--||||JLLF7F-J|F-7LJFJFJ.F7F-JLJF7|L7||||||F----JF-JFJL7||FJFJ|F7FJ|||FJ||L7|FJF-7|||LJL7F7LJL7F---J||F7FJL7L--7|||L-J|L7L7J|LFJ--77.
FJ.-7.|.-LLLJ.F-JLJF7|L7L--JFJF-JLJF7F7|LJ|LJ||FJ||F7F-7L77L7FJLJL7L7LJ|L7LJ||FJ|LLJL-JJLJ|L-7F||L7F7||F7F7|LJLJF7L7F-J||L7F-JFL-J.J.77F|--|
L-7FJ.F-|7J.FFL---7|LJFJF7F7L7|F7F7||||L--77FJ|L7||||L7|FJF-JL---7L-JF7L7L-7LJL7|F---7LF7FJF-JFJL7|||||||||L----J|FJL-7||FJL----7.-L-LJLLJ7|
J-777.7LL---LF----J|F-JFJLJL-JLJ||LJLJ|F--JFJFJ7||LJ|FJ||JL-7F7F7L7F-JL-JF7L-7FJ|L--7L-J|L7L7FL7FJLJLJ|||||F7F7F7|L7F-J||L-7F7F7L7.|J|JFL-JJ
LF|J7LJFJ.|7FL--7F-JL7FJF-------JL-7F-JL-7FJFJF-JL7|LJFJL-7|||LJL-JL7F--7|L7FJL7||F7L--7L-JFJF-JL---7FJ|||||LJ||LJ7|L-7||F7LJ|||FJ7F7FFJJJL7
FL7-|J.JJ7LFF---JL77|||FJF7F-7F7F-7||F-7FJ|FJFJF-7|F--JF7FJFJ|F--7F-JL7FJ|J||F7||FJL--7L7F-J7L-7F--7|L7||||L-7|L7F7L-7||||L7FJ||L--77FJL-7|F
7J.||-7J7|7|L-7F7FJF7||L7|||FJ|||FJ|||FJ|FJ|FL7|FJ||F7FJ|L7L7LJF-JL7F7|L7|FJ|||LJL-7F7L-JL---7FJL-7LJFJ|||L7FJL7LJL7.|||LJFJL-JL7F-JJL-7|LJ-
-7F-J.LF-|-L..||LJFJLJ|.LJLJL7|||L-JLJL7|L-JF7||L7|LJ|L7L7|FJF7L--7||||FJ|L7||L----J|L7F7F7F7|L7F7|F7L-J||FJ|F-JF-7L7LJL7FJ7J|JL|L--7J.|F7LL
LFJLLF-7LF7JF-LJLL|F-7L-7F---J|LJF-----JL---J||L7||F-JFJFJ|L7||F7FJ||||L7L7|||F7F---JL||||LJLJFJ||||L--7LJ|FJL7FJ|L7L-7FJL-7F77-L7F-J.77FJLL
.|7F|LJL-J|7|LLF--LJLL7FJ|F-7FJF-JF---7F7F---JL-JLJ|F7L7L-JFJ||||L7LJ||FJFJ||LJ||F7F--J||L7F--JFJ|LJF-7L-7|L7FJL--7|F7||F-7LJ|--FJ|7|F-FJ7.|
F--7LJJ.|L|.L7FL-LJ||FLJFLJFJL7|F-JF--J||L----7F---J||FJF--JFJ||L7L-7||L7|FJ|FFJ||LJF-7||FJ|F7FJFJF7L7L--JL-JL7F-7|||||||FJF-JJ.L7L7-|JL|F.F
LJ7||JF-|JFJ7L--|J||7FLLJ-LL7FJLJF7L--7|L7F---JL---7|||7L7F7|FJ|||F-J||FJ|L7L7L7|L7FJFJ|LJFJ|||-L7|L-JF7-F--7F|L7LJLJLJLJL7|J|.-LL7|7L77LL-7
F-7.-.7FL.LJF7J-|F|.J7LLL-|7LJLLFJL---J|-|L--77F7F-J|||F7LJLJL7|FJL-7||L7|LL7|FJL7|L7L7L-7L7||L7FJL---JL-JF7L7|FJ|-|||7|.LLJJFJ..F||7-FJ|.|J
L.L-LFF-FJ.-L-J.FLF-F7-.FL|F-77FJF7F7F7L7|F-7L7||L7FJ|||L-----J|L7F-J|L7|L7F|||F-J|FJFJF7L7||L-J|F7F7F--7FJ|FJ|L-7-J7JFJ-L|L-FJ-|-||--FJL-|J
.FL7.-FJ|L7.||L-JFJ|LF.77FLL7L-JFJLJLJ|FJ|L7L7LJ|FJ||LJL--7F7F7|FJL-7|FJL7L7||LJF-J|FJFJL-JLJJF-J|LJ|L-7LJFLJ7L--J||JL|L77|..|7-|.LJJFJ.|-|-
|JF-L7LF|.-7J.77.|F7F7-77F-L|F7FJF--7FJL7L7L7L7FJ|FJF-----J|||LJL7F-JLJF-JFJ||F-JF7|L7L---7F--JF7L-7|F7L7F-7J7J7|JF---JFJLFJ7F-7LL777FJ.7F-J
L-F-LF--J.JJ.FL77L-JF|FLJ||.LJLJ-|F7LJF7|J|FJL|L7||7|F-7F-7|LJF--JL--7JL7FJF||L-7||L7|F-7FJL-7FJL7FJLJL7LJFJLJ.FJ.F-|F-J77|L-JJJ-|LLLL-|-L.|
7LF7.FJ|FFJ|F|JL7--7.LJ-FL7F|J..FLJ|F7||L7LJF-JFJ|L7||FJ|FJ|F-JF-7F-7L7||L7FJ|F-J||FJ|L7|L-7FJ|F-JL--7FJF-J|J.FLJF|F-7F-7---J.||FL7L7J|L|J.|
L.-|--J|.|.7--7J7J..FJL-L-J||--FF-|LJ||L7L7FL-7L7L7|LJ|FJ|FJL-7|FJL7L-JFJFJ|FJL7FJ||FJFJL7FJ|FJL7F7F-JL7L--7|FJL-J|7.|7|JLLL-7FL---7L.---777
J-L|-|7.FF7|.L|.|J|.---|7|7F7FLL|FFJL||LL7|JJLL7|FJ|F-J|FJL-7FJ|L-7L--7|FJJ||JJLJ7LJL7L7.LJ7||7LLJ|L--7L7F7|J-|L|7.F-7||7-L77L7-J..F-FL.LJ-7
L7|F-7J7-FJ7F7LJ-F7.F|-F-77LL7LJ|LJLFJ|-LLJJL|LLJL7|L-7||F--JL7L-7|F7FJLJFLLJF--FF---JFJF---JL7-F7|F7FJJ||LJJFL.-J.LFJJJF-7L|7J|L-F-FLJ.|||.
.|-L-|L-JL.77L7|-L|-FF.||.--FF.|F-||L-JLL-LL-F7LF-J|LFJ||L77-FJF7|||LJJF77||F|J|LL--7FJJL7F-7FJFJLJ|LJF7LJ..-7JFJ-L--JJ-J-LLFJ.||FJJ.|.JLF|J
.LJL77-JF|7|7-LL.LJLLJ.LF-|-7.LLJ.F-JL|-L7L|.7||L--JJ|FJL7L-7L-J|||L--7||L-L7L77.J7F||F--J|FJL7L7F7L--JL7J77F-J||F|J||.L|J|F|7-L-JJ77J.FFFJ.
-J..L7JLFJF7-7F|77L7-77F-FJ-|.|-F.|L|L7|LJ7F7JFF|J|F-JL7LL--J|LFJ||F-7LJL7.L--.J-FFFJ||F7FJL-7L7|||F-7F-J|FF-.FLJ-J.7F7.-.F7|FJFJ7LFJF-|-JF7
J--7JL7FJF|LJ-LJL--JL|F--JJ-|FF7LLF--FJJ|F-.7|FLJ|LL--7L----7J7L7||L7|F7FJJJ|FJJ-FFL-JLJ|L7|FJFJLJ|L7LJLLFFJL|77||7.L|LJL-JLLJ7-7LJ|-J.||.||
|-L|JL||F7L777||LJ-L.FJF7J.FLF--7FLF-|JL7-LJ-|L|-JJ..FJF-7F-JJFL|||FJ||||J.-JJ|F-|JJ|FF-JFJFJFJ7.||FJ-J7|J|7F|-L-J-J-J7J.|FJLJ.FJF7..F77L7-L
|||.F.LL||-L-J7-LFF7-|--LJ.LF|JLJ7FF7L|FF-7J.LFJ-77F-|FJFJ|.|J|FLJLJLLJLJJ7|LJFLJLLJ|7L-7|-L-JJ7.FJ|-F7JL--J-J7JJLFJLL7-FFL77FLJJL7-.7J||F-.
FLJ7LLJFL-7FJF77.LL7J|F||7|-LJ7.FJ7|LF77JLJ7FF-LJ-J77LJ|L-J--7.L-L|JL.||JLJF-FJL77.-.L.LLJJ.|.F|FL7|-L7FFJ-L-J|J7FJ7JFJ7|F7L77|FF-L-7|-LFJ.F
FJ.7LL--L-7J--L-7LJJL-|-FFL-F------JF|-7-7.-FLJ.L|LL|JL|JLJJLL7L-JJJLFJ.LL-JLJL7--F--J-|.J.L-J-LFJLJ7J-7-JLLFLJ.J.LL.JJ-JLJL-J|---L7LFJLLL|.'''.split("\n")


class Node:
    instances = dict()

    def __init__(self, char, row, column):
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
        self.char = char
        self.__class__.instances[f'{row}-{column}'] = self
        self.part_of_loop = False

    @property
    def connects_to(self):
        if self.char == "F":
            return {self.down, self.right}
        if self.char == "L":
            return {self.up, self.right}
        if self.char == "J":
            return {self.up, self.left}
        if self.char == "7":
            return {self.down, self.left}
        if self.char == "|":
            return {self.down, self.up}
        if self.char == "-":
            return {self.left, self.right}
        return set()

    @property
    def key(self):
        return self.__class__.get_key(self.row, self.column)

    @property
    def up(self):
        return self.__class__.get_instance(self.row - 1, self.column)

    @property
    def down(self):
        return self.__class__.get_instance(self.row + 1, self.column)

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.__class__.get_instance(self.row, self.column + 1)

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.__class__.get_instance(self.row, self.column - 1)

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, row, column):
        key = cls.get_key(row, column)
        if key in cls.instances:
            return cls.instances[key]
        else:
            if 0 <= row < len(grid) and 0 <= column < len(grid[0]):
                char = grid[row][column]
                return cls(char, row, column)
            else:
                return None

    @classmethod
    def get_key(cls, row, column):
        return f'{row}-{column}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.row},{self.column}: {self.char}'


for i, row in enumerate(grid):
    if 'S' in row:
        j = row.index('S')
        start = Node.get_instance(i, j)
        start.char = '-'



previous_step = start
current_step = list(start.connects_to)[0]
buggy_node = Node.get_instance(51, 139)


while current_step != start:
    next_step = list(current_step.connects_to.difference([previous_step]))[0]
    previous_step, current_step = current_step, next_step

    if current_step == buggy_node:
        if not previous_step.row < current_step.row:
            print(current_step.right.down)


# weird = [node for node in set() if node.column > 0]
```

The code above was not the exact code in which I noticed this. I've tried to strip as much code as possible that still caused the bug to occur.

Weirdly enough, during this process. The bug would sometimes flip around. (sometimes the code would only cause an error if the line was commented out and sometimes, the code would only cause an error if the line was executed as code.

It doesn't end there:
If the class Puzzle is removed from the start of the program (it is no longer referenced in the code), the code won't run into an error in either situation.

Comment: What's the full error traceback?

Comment: I always get the error when executing the code by calling `python thecode.py` in Windows `cmd` or from VS Code, but can reproduce the strange behaviour when executing the code from IDLE by pressing F5.

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: @mkrieger1 And with the line you always got the error and without it you never got the error?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I get a mix of error and no error in both cases. What Python version? I used 3.11.4.

Comment: I used 3.8.1 in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has to do with this line:

```
current_step = list(start.connects_to)[0]
```

`start.connects_to` is a set, which has no defined order, so if you convert it to a list and take the first element, the result can be arbitrary.

Changing the structure of the code (e.g. adding or removing a statement at the end) changes the internal state of the interpreter and can influence which element you get, but this depends on the implementation and I can't explain it.

Depending on the initial value of `current_step`, later during the execution of the code, either `print(current_step.right.down)` is executed while `current_step.right` is `None`, or not.